# Why this error pops up as I try to read a netCDF file?

Tags: python, netcdf4

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what is behind this error, as I'm new in programming.
When I try to read a netCDF4 file, the following error pops up:

**File "/home/thiago/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PROJ_LIB'**

Trying to use the simple method as follows:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset as dt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap as bm

data = 'sst.wkmean.1981-1989.nc'
```

I already uninstalled and reinstalled netCDF4 package but, as I'm unexperienced, something tells me that this error's origin could be associated with lack of updating of packages (don't dominate terminal programing), bad directory installing or something like that. I use the deepin distribution of linux, but looking foward to change to ubuntu as community and tutorials as well spread throughout the internet.

Comment: Are you sure this is netCDF problem? Can you try without importing `Basemap` (do not  add line `from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap as bm`) as `PROJ` is more related to that package.

Comment: seems to be a `basemap` + `conda` issue, see e.g. https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/419 - I remember having similar issues with Anaconda.